Why did the author use the simple past instead of the simple present?
Practice English Usage(by Michael Swan) says, "We often use the simples present to talk about timeless truths..." but why did the author use the simple past in the passage? Did he just want to highlight the past event?

Many people look for safety and security in popular thinking. They
figure that if a lot of people are doing something, then it must be
right. It must be a good idea. If most people accept it, then it
probably represents fairness, equality, compassion, and sensitivity,
right? Not necessarily. Popular thinking said the earth was the center
of the universe, yet Copernicus studied the stars and planets and
proved mathematically that the earth and the other planets in our
solar system revolved around the sun. Popular thinking said
surgery didn’t require clean instruments, yet Joseph Lister studied
the high death rates in hospitals and introduced antiseptic practices
that immediately saved lives. Popular thinking said that women
shouldn’t have the right to vote, yet people like Emmeline Pankhurst
and Susan B. Anthony fought for and won that right. Popular thinking
put the Nazis into power in Germany, yet Hitler's regime murdered
millions and nearly destroyed Europe. We must always remember there is
a huge difference between acceptance and intelligence. People may say
that there’s safety in numbers, but that’s not always true.

How Successful People Think: Change Your Thinking, Change Your Life
By John C. Maxwell

Because it matches the entire sentence which is in the past. He discovered the Earth is round. OR He discovered the Earth was roun. Both are fine.

It's a second-cousin to reported speech:  "Those early experiments showed that water was made of hydrogen and oxygen."

Look at the advice you quoted: "We often use the simple present to talk about timeless truths."  It doesn’t say always.
